# How to immigrate from current federation system for Web Microsoft Azure databases to the new Elastic scale out in the Basic databases

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-elastic-scale, sql-azure-federations

we discover that the Microsoft Sql Azure Web databases are going to retired in the September 2015.
our application (PHP application) is working on federation mechanism.

how to convert our federation to the new elastic scale out?
is there is a new Sql federation command to create new federations and control them?

is there is an easy way to move data smoothly from the federation mechanism to the new scale out (Web to Basic) databases?

Answer (score 1):

there's no SQL command for doing the migration, the migration steps and a migration utility is available at this [link](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-elastic-scale-federation-migration/). You will have to do some code changes on your app as well.

Answer (score 1):

The new Elastic Scale features in Azure SQL DB are provided through client libraries that currently are available only with ADO.Net.   A complete summary of capabilities can be found at this [link](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-elastic-scale-documentation-map/).  Included are tools that allow migration from federations "in-place".   However direct PHP api support is not currently available.  I would like to understand your scenario better so please email me directly -- stuarto (at) Microsoft (dot) com.